# PosrgreSQL multi tenant sharding balance

Tags: postgresql, architecture, amazon-rds, multi-tenant

Currently in our product each customer has it's own Postgres (on RDS), and inside that postgres all the customer data is saved and presented to the customer in the app.

We want to change the architecture to a more multi tenant approach, to improve scalability, maintenance, utilization (cost).

The classic approach might be adding a `tenant_id` column, but then to support many clients 1 instance might not be enough, so we would shard the data across multiple databases, according to the `tenant_id` hash, so the customer data is in the same instance, and 1 instance could host multiple customers.

The only problem I can think of with this approach is that if customer sizes are different (1 is small, 1 is huge), or customers can join or leave, then we might end up with unbalanced shards, where 1 would a lot of data and another would not. Theoretically it's probably good to choose a shard key the is uniformly distributed but it's not really possible in our case (and I imagine in many classic B2B saas), where the app is always showing 1 customer data.

Any ideas on how to mitigate that downside, or different approaches for achieving multi tenancy?

Thanks!